# How to interpret the ahadith about the prohibition of praying between the pillars of a mosque?

Tags: salat, fiqh, hadith-interpretation, masjid

We may read in the sunnah:

- > “We were forbidden to form a row between two pillars at the time of the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ), and we would be repelled from them forcefully.” ([Sunan ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/urn/1310540))
- > "We prayed behind one of the Amirs, the people compelled us such that we prayed between two columns. When we had prayed, Anas bin Malik said: 'We would be prevented from this during the time of Allah's Messenger.'" ([Jami' at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/2/81), [sunan an-Nasa-i](https://sunnah.com/nasai/10/45) and [sunan abi Daowd](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/2/283))

  Imam at-Tirmdihi commented this hadith saying that some scholars have considered forming rows between the pillars as makrooh while others considered it permissible.

Is there an explanation why praying between pillars is considered as forbidden or frowned upon?
How should we understand such ahadith and interpret them as usually in bigger mosque you may find yourself in almost all positions somewhere between two pillars?